# jQuery .load() with Relative Path - XMLHttpRequest Cannot Load - Workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

I have a **locally-stored** project whose directory structure is the following (I minimized non-relevant folders):

[image: directory structure]

What I want to do is that in an HTML file, like `index.html`, to add a `<header>` such that its contents would be loaded from an external HTML file, so all of what I'll have to write in `index.html` would be `<header>`, and my solution would load the content automatically.

To do this, I'd like to use JavaScript (preferably jQuery, but I'll accept other solutions if they work and jQuery doesn't, or if they work and executed faster than jQuery).

I don't think that I should use an `<iframe>` due to the fact that it'd probably increase loading times more than using jQuery/JavaScript (which, like I said, is what works now, **when the website is live**).

Right now, I'm using the jQuery `.load()` function. I don't know much about jQuery, but I've been told that it should work locally - and it doesn't, for me.
My browser's console shows me the problem:

> jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/GalGr/Desktop/eiomw/header.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

And I'm trying to overcome it.

This code works on [my live website](http://eiomw.surge.sh/) - it *might* not be updated to the code of the files that I linked to below, but it doesn't matter - their code matters.

This is the `index.html` file: 
[index.html](http://pastebin.com/8t4dM0iE)

This is the `header.html` file:
[header.html](http://pastebin.com/vF2RuBa5)

This is `main_script.js:
[main_script](http://pastebin.com/jwFXEeSq)

Comment: So you have said what you want to happen but... what have you tried? This isn't the place to dump your idea and have someone code it up for you at your request. Please update your question and display the relevant source code.

Comment: This is a place to solve problems. That's what this website is meant for, as far as I know. I'm asking for help with finding a solution for this code and files structure, considering that I don't have a server.

Comment: I added a problem that happens to me with jQuery's `.load()` function. Please cancel your down-vote. I didn't know in advance that it should work locally, too.

Comment: Also, in my code you can see what I tried.

That's why I added the JS file.

Comment: I added information about the problem that I'm having.
Please cancel your downvote.

Also, the problem that I'm having doesn't necessarily has to do with the fact that my post had "problems" of missing information.

After the edit that shows the error that I get, I I've been asking for a workaround for this problem just the same as I did before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Using phpStorm's built-in localhost, I was able to emulate a server that handles my requests and responses.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having a problem with this locally is mainly down to security measures in your browser.

Essentially whenever you're using jQuery's `load()` function it makes a separate HTTP request (approach known as AJAX) for the file or URL you give it.

Modern browsers enforce that the URL you request using AJAX methods is from the same origin (server) as a security feature to stop pages randomly loading content from anywhere on the internet in the background. In your case it seems like this shouldn't affect you because you're browsing your pages locally and the request you're making using `load()` is also for a local file (header.html).

However, I am assuming you're just opening up the page directly in your browser, so your browser's URL will look something like 'file:///C:/Users...' (similar example in the error message you gave). This means your browser is directly reading the file from disk and interpreting it as HTML to display the page. It seems likely you don't actually have a local HTTP server hosting the page, otherwise the URL would start with 'http://'. It is for this reason that the browser is giving the security error, even though your AJAX request for header.html is technically from the same source as the page it is executed on.

Your server will have an HTTP server which it's using to host the pages, and so everything works fine as you're then using HTTP as normal, and this security feature does not get in your way.

I would suggest that you simply install an HTTP server locally on your dev machine. You don't even need to 'install' one per-se, there are loads of development HTTP servers that just run standalone, so you start them up when you want to browse your local HTML files. As you appear to be on Windows, I'd check out either IIS (Windows' HTTP server) or IIS Express (like IIS but runs standalone). There are also many others available like Apache, Nginx, etc. etc.

If you do this, you can host your pages on something like 'http://localhost/index.html'. Then, any AJAX requests you make for local files will work fine, just like your server.

Hope that makes sense, and I'm not telling you something you already know?

Comment: I didn't know that `load()` makes an HTTP request - I'm not very familiar with AJAX, and someone told me that it should also work locally (which isn't true, from my understanding now).

Everything else that you've said, I know.

Someone told me that in the IDE that I use, which is PhpStorm, there's a built-in localhost service, which I didn't know about when I posted the question, so now I'm using it.

I'm going to vote up your comment just because of the information about the `load` function, and not mark it as a solution, as I already solved the problem.

Comment: No problem at all, glad you managed to find a method that worked for you locally. FWIW I always use some sort of server to host HTTP pages, otherwise you get unpredictable stuff like this. AJAX is worth looking into and jQuery makes everything so much easier, definitely worth knowing the core parts of it if you ever plan on using JS do anything non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using something more straight foreword like [mustache.js](http://mustache.github.io/) ?